# How to move an object drawn in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The figure below shows a car climbing a hill, but the wheels are not on the right place. I used to have a rectangle which was easy to more about but how do I move a more complex object? In the code you can see the rectangle, which is commented out, and the new car. I could add the displacement to all the x-coordinates but I am sure there is better way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\ang}{30}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% triangle:
\draw [draw = orange, fill = orange!15] (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (\ang:10)
    coordinate [pos=.35] (M) |- coordinate (B) (O);

% angles:
\draw [draw = orange] (O) ++(.8,0) arc (0:\ang:0.8) 
    node [pos=.4, left] {$\alpha$};
\draw [draw = orange] (B) rectangle ++(-0.3,0.3);

\begin{scope} [-latex,rotate=\ang,every node/.style={rotate=\ang}]

% % Object (rectangle)
% \draw [fill = purple!30,
%   draw = purple!50] (M) ++ (0,0.2) rectangle ++ (4.5,1.5);


% Object Car    
\draw [fill = purple!30,
    draw = purple!50,-] (0,0.2) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) --(3.2,1)--(4,1)--(4.5,0.7)--(4.5,0.2) --(0,0.2);


% Object (wheel1)
\draw [fill=lightgray] (M) ++ (0.7,0.4) coordinate (w1)  circle (.4cm);
% Object (wheel2)
\draw [fill=lightgray] (M) ++ (3.5,0.4) coordinate (w2)  circle (.4cm);

% Weight and its projections
\draw [dashed] (M) ++ (2,.9) coordinate (MM) -- ++ (0,-1.29)
    node [ right] {$mg\cos{\theta}$};

\draw [dashed] (MM) -- ++ (-0.75,0) 
    node [midway, above] {$mg\sin{\theta}$};

\draw (MM) -- ++ (-\ang-90:1.5)
    node [above left ] {$mg$};

% Normal Force 2
\draw (M) ++ (0.3,-1.1) coordinate (N2) -- ++ (0,1.1)
node [very near start, left] {$N_2$};
% Normal Force 1
\draw (M) ++ (3.5,-1.1) coordinate (N1) -- ++ (0,1.1)
node [very near start, right] {$N_1$};

% Speed
\draw (M) ++ (1.5,2.2) coordinate (w2) -- ++ (0.75,0)
    node [above] {$v$};

% Traction force
\draw (M) ++ (-0.8,0) coordinate (TF) -- ++ (1,0)
    node [very near start, above] {$F_t$};
    
\end{scope}

\begin{scope} [rotate=\ang,every node/.style={rotate=\ang}]

\draw  [blue] (MM) --  ++ (2.7,0)   node [very near end, left] {$ $};
    
\draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (8,0.9) --  (8,0) node [midway, right] {$h$};;

\draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (3.8,-0.9) --  (5.5,-0.9) node [midway, above] {$b$};;
\draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (MM)++ (0,-1.8) --  (7,-0.9) node [midway, above] {$a$};;

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE
With the input from @blackmild I have now achieved what I was trying to do.

By putting the picture in the header:

```
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}},
         vehicle/.pic={
        code={\tikzset{scale=10/10}
\draw [fill = purple!30,
    draw = purple!50,-] (-0.2,0.2) -- (-0.2,1) -- (1,1) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) --(3.2,1)--(4,1)--(4.5,0.7)--(4.5,0.2) --(-0.2,0.2);
% Object (wheel1)
\draw [fill=lightgray] (0.4,0.4) coordinate (w1)  circle (.4cm);
% Object (wheel2)
\draw [fill=lightgray] (3.6,0.4) coordinate (w2)  circle (.4cm);
  }}
}
```

and using the picture in code.

```
% Object Car    
\path (3.4,0) pic {vehicle};
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method that I use is using definitions, it allows you to create objects with attributes such as position, inclination, color, put some coordinates according to the name of the object, in short, in the code there are other variants, including the change of direction, I added a tesla model to test the conversion from svg to tikz, of course you could easily import another vector drawing in pdf, but I decided to make the code portable.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, arrows.meta}
\newcommand{\ang}{30}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        %Simplified car [objet like]:\Simplecar(position)[rotation][color]{orientation}{name}
        \def\SimpleCar(#1)[#2][#3]#4#5{
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,xscale=#4]
                %path(body)
                \draw [fill = #3!30,xshift=-10mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (2.5,1.5) --(3.2,1)--(4,1)--(4.5,0.7)--(4.5,0.2) --(0,0.2);
                % path wheels
                \draw [fill=#3!50!gray] (0mm,4mm) circle (4mm);
                \draw [fill=#3!50!gray] (25mm,4mm) circle (4mm);
                \coordinate (#5-W1) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (#5-W2) at (25mm,0);
                \coordinate (#5-G) at (12.5mm,10mm);
                % Speed
                \draw [>=latex,<-](#5-G)++(0.5,0.7) -- ++ (-1,0) node [midway,sloped,anchor=-90] {$v$};
                % Traction force
                \draw [>=latex,<-](#5-W1) -- ++ (-1,0) node [midway,anchor=90] {$F_t$};
            \end{scope}
        }
        %More detailed car [obtained using inkscape svg to tikz converter]:\MDCar(position)[rotation][color]{name}
        \def\MDCar(#1)[#2][#3]#4{
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2]
                %path(body)
                \filldraw[scale=0.5,x=1mm,y=1mm,yscale=-1,xscale=-1,fill=#3!50,xshift=-235,yshift=-90] (59.9429,0.0029) .. controls (58.2798,0.0161) and (56.5224,0.0709) .. (54.6592,0.1699) .. controls (51.8698,0.3182) and (49.2785,0.7036) .. (46.8955,1.2407) .. controls (46.9004,1.2391) and (46.9067,1.2365) .. (46.9116,1.2349) .. controls (35.0588,3.3135) and (25.0020,10.1030) .. (25.0020,10.1030) -- (24.1113,10.1660) .. controls (22.2803,10.1061) and (21.6259,10.2123) .. (17.5122,11.0391) .. controls (15.2265,11.1391) and (13.1653,11.4703) .. (11.3730,11.9180) .. controls (11.2904,11.9383) and (11.2097,11.9609) .. (11.1284,11.9824) .. controls (8.6666,12.6223) and (6.7447,13.4848) .. (5.6074,14.3101) .. controls (2.5699,14.9763) and (0.3984,16.7520) .. (0.3984,16.7520) .. controls (-0.1586,17.2949) and (0.0797,17.2023) .. (0.0044,17.6191) .. controls (-0.0709,18.0360) and (0.7119,21.0322) .. (0.7119,21.0322) .. controls (0.7119,21.0322) and (0.0821,22.9131) .. (0.5215,23.0918) .. controls (0.9609,23.2703) and (1.0903,23.4957) .. (1.4604,24.4233) .. controls (-0.8220,25.6494) and (0.4983,26.3315) .. (1.5059,26.9150) .. controls (2.5136,27.4983) and (5.1650,28.1973) .. (6.5098,27.9229) .. controls (6.4949,27.8726) and (6.4886,27.8209) .. (6.4746,27.7705) -- (8.3862,26.9062) -- (23.4346,26.2646) -- (25.2979,27.3164) .. controls (25.3045,27.3313) and (25.3242,27.3955) .. (25.3242,27.3955) .. controls (25.3242,27.3955) and (25.5918,27.6023) .. (26.2236,27.4849) .. controls (27.8013,27.0856) and (67.5264,26.7188) .. (67.5264,26.7188) .. controls (67.5264,26.7188) and (71.0655,26.7059) .. (72.3955,27.2095) .. controls (72.9263,27.4105) and (73.2239,27.3453) .. (73.4019,27.1245) .. controls (73.7709,27.0085) and (75.1701,26.5817) .. (75.4629,26.5400) .. controls (75.7840,26.4940) and (90.4210,25.8970) .. (90.3750,25.8970) .. controls (90.3293,25.8970) and (92.2559,26.6777) .. (92.2559,26.6777) .. controls (92.2559,26.6777) and (92.3225,26.6082) .. (92.3320,26.5986) .. controls (92.5830,26.6361) and (92.9367,26.6106) .. (93.4336,26.4961) .. controls (95.4068,26.0414) and (96.8291,25.3066) .. (96.8291,25.3066) .. controls (96.8291,25.3066) and (98.1069,23.5919) .. (98.3862,22.9688) .. controls (98.6655,22.3454) and (98.4976,22.1118) .. (98.4976,22.1118) .. controls (98.4976,22.1118) and (98.8375,20.8511) .. (99.2549,19.8252) .. controls (99.6719,18.8000) and (99.6148,18.6385) .. (98.9854,18.0322) .. controls (98.2215,17.0284) and (97.8547,14.8710) .. (98.0010,13.9409) .. controls (98.0616,13.5558) and (98.0431,13.1384) .. (98.0083,12.7661) .. controls (98.0515,11.7298) and (97.7331,10.8516) .. (97.4692,10.3418) .. controls (97.3419,9.9538) and (97.2028,9.5918) .. (97.0620,9.4497) .. controls (96.6727,9.0568) and (97.2353,8.9554) .. (97.7930,8.6543) .. controls (98.3509,8.3530) and (97.8727,8.0535) .. (97.5088,8.0420) .. controls (97.1451,8.0305) and (96.4688,7.9805) .. (96.4688,7.9805) .. controls (95.4388,7.9064) and (92.8843,6.7387) .. (85.3447,4.1309) -- (85.3271,4.1133) .. controls (85.3259,4.1146) and (85.3240,4.1207) .. (85.3228,4.1221) .. controls (85.3044,4.1157) and (85.2943,4.1123) .. (85.2759,4.1060) .. controls (78.6238,1.8073) and (71.5847,-0.0896) .. (59.9429,0.0029) -- cycle;
                 path(wheel1)
                %path wheels
                \draw [fill=#3!50!gray] (0,4mm) coordinate (#4.w1)  circle (4mm);
                \draw [fill=#3!50!gray] (32mm,4mm) coordinate (#4.w2)  circle (4mm);
                %Special coordinates.
                \coordinate (#4-W1) at (0,0);
                \coordinate (#4-W2) at (32mm,0);
                \coordinate (#4-G) at (16mm,7mm);
                % Speed
                \draw [>=latex,<-](#4-G)++(0.5,1.2) -- ++ (-1,0) node [midway,anchor=-90] {$v$};
                % Traction force
                \draw [>=latex,<-](#4-W1) -- ++ (-1,0) node [midway,anchor=90] {$F_t$};
            \end{scope}
        }
    
        %Another draw code anidation
        %Vectors{objet_name}{angle}{direction}
        \def\Vectors#1#2#3{
            \begin{scope} [>=latex,rotate=\ang,every node/.style={rotate=\ang}]
                % Weight and its projections
                \draw [dashed,->](#1-G) -- ++ (0,-1.29)node [midway,sloped,anchor=-90,scale=0.9] {$mg\cos{\theta}$};
                \draw [dashed,->] (#1-G) -- ++ (-0.75,0) node [midway, sloped,anchor=-90,scale=0.9] {$mg\sin{\theta}$};
                \draw [->](#1-G) -- ++ (-\ang-90:1.5) node [midway, sloped,anchor=-90,scale=0.9] {$mg$};
                % Normal Force 2
                \draw [<-](#1-W1) -- ++ (0,-1.1) node [pos=0.9, anchor=90] {$N_1$};
                % Normal Force 1
                \draw [<-](#1-W2) -- ++ (0,-1.1) node [pos=0.9, anchor=90] {$N_2$};
                \draw [blue] (#1-G) --  ++ (2.7,0) coordinate (temp);
                \draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (temp) --  (temp|-#1-W1) node [midway, right] {$h$};
                \draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (#1-W2)++(0,-0.9) coordinate (temp) --  (temp-|#1-G) node [midway, above] {$b$};
                \draw [blue,>=triangle 45, <->] (#1-W1)++ (0,-0.9) coordinate (temp) --  (temp-|#1-G) node [midway, above] {$a$};;
            \end{scope}
        }
        %Start drawing the thing...
        % Hepl lines to work with obsolute coordinates:
        \def\wcanvas{15}
        \def\hcanvas{12}
        \draw[red!5,step=0.25] (-1,-1) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \draw[cyan!40,step=1,line width=1] (-1,-1) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
        \foreach \x in {-1, ..., \wcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=90] at (\x,-1) {\tiny\x};
        }
        \foreach \y in {-1, ..., \hcanvas} {%
            \node[anchor=0] at (-1,\y) {\tiny\y};

        }
    
        % Terrain
        \draw [draw = orange, fill = orange!15,opacity=0.5]
        (0mm,0mm) coordinate (O)
            -- (\ang:8) coordinate [pos=0.35](M) 
            -- ++(0:2) 
            -- ++(\ang:7) coordinate [pos=0.75](N)
            |- coordinate (B) (O);
        \draw [draw = orange]
        (O) 
            ++(.8,0)
            arc (0:\ang:0.8) node [pos=.4, left] {$\alpha$};
        \draw [draw = orange] 
        (B) 
            rectangle ++(-0.3,0.3);
        
        % Starting drawing cars in some absolute and coordinate name positions.
        \SimpleCar(0.5,10)[0][purple]{1}{CAR-01}
        \MDCar(0.5,7)[0][blue]{CAR-02}      
        \SimpleCar(N)[\ang][lime]{-1}{CAR-03}
        \MDCar(M)[\ang][red]{CAR-04}        
        \Vectors{CAR-03}{\ang}{->}
        \Vectors{CAR-04}{\ang}{->}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @J Leon V. a very nice solution indeed. Also learned about inkscape svg to tikz converter which will be useful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long comment. Your code is not neat. `pgfplots` is not needed here.

For the wheels, you can get the center `weelcenter1` of the first wheel by following the path from `O` to `M`, then turn clock-wise with the angle 90 degrees (`.4` means `.4cm`=`4mm` the radius of the wheels)

```
\path (O)--(M)--([turn]90:.4) coordinate (weelcenter1);
```

and then you can draw the wheel

```
\draw[fill=gray] (weelcenter1) circle(.4);
```

Similarly for the second wheel.

[image]

```
% Object (wheel1)
%\draw [fill=lightgray] (M) ++ (0.7,0.4) coordinate (w1)  circle (.4);
% Object (wheel2)
%\draw [fill=lightgray] (M) ++ (3.5,0.4) coordinate (w2)  circle (.4);

%\fill[red] (M) circle(.1);
\path 
(O)--(M)--([turn]90:.4) coordinate (weelcenter1)
(O)--(M) coordinate[pos=.4] (Mt)
(O)--(Mt)--([turn]90:.4) coordinate (weelcenter2)
;
\draw[fill=gray] (weelcenter1) circle(.4) (weelcenter2) circle(.4);
\fill[red] (weelcenter1) circle(.1) (weelcenter2) circle(.1);
```

Comment: I want to move the chassis, not the wheels. Otherwise the measurements will not be in the right place.

Comment: @JohnW.deBurgh If so, you can draw the chassis (including wheels) as a pic (say named `chassis`), then put the pic along with `\path (A)--(B) pic[sloped,pos=.6]{chassis};`